# Browsers do not cache response sent by MediaView

Tags: cakephp, browser, browser-cache, cakephp-2.0

This is my controller code:

```
  $this->viewClass = 'Media';
    $params = array(
      'id'        => $filename '.gif',
      'name'      => $filename ,
      'download'  => false,
      'extension' => 'gif',
      'path'      => $folderpath,
      'cache'     => '+30 days',
      'modified' => '@' . filemtime($pathtofile),

    );
  $this->set($params);
```

and the response:

[image: firebug screenshot]

Debug is disabled in core.php. However, the browser (Firefox, Chrome) never caches the file and always download the whole thing. Is this because of the **200 OK** response? How can I fix it?

**EDIT**
I probably should have added a sample of the actual request URL

http://localhost/mycontroller/mymediaaction/2345

I resolved the issue by setting the **name** attribute to the action parameter instead of the actual file name. I still appreciate an answer with some explanation of this behavior.

Comment: looks like your last modified is kind of invalid (set to 0). maybe this plays into it?

Comment: @TiCL I'm running into the same problem. Images in my webroot have a status of "304 Not Modified". Images outside of the webroot that I stream with the "Media" view have a status of "200 OK" and the browser always has to download the entire image. Would you mind elaborating on how you resolved this issue?

Comment: Never mind. Just had to add this: `if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) && strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) == filemtime($pathtofile)) {header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified'); exit;}`

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet for a controller action would either serve a **304** response or the file. I think that the `checkNotModified` functionality should be done by the `MediaView::render` function internally, similar to the `AssetDispatcher`. But for the time being this snippet may be of help.

```
$modified = @filemtime(ROOT . $dir . $filename);
$this->response->modified($modified);
if ($this->response->checkNotModified($this->request))
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->send();
}
else
{
    $this->viewClass = 'Media';
    $params = array('id' => $filename,
        'cache' => '+1 day',
        'modified' => '@' . $modified, // Must be a string to work. See MediaView->render()
        'path' => ROOT . $dir);
    $this->set($params);
}
return;
```